# Django Admin: change displayed column name in inline ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I try to translate Django Admin site and I have a problem with `ManyToMany` `TabularInline`. My `models.py` are:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    (...)
    specializations = models.ManyToManyField(Specialization, blank=True, verbose_name='Specjalizacje')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Lekarz'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Lekarze'

class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=191, verbose_name='Nazwa')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Specjalizacja'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Specjalizacje'
```

And my `admin.py` looks like:

```
class SpecializationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Doctor.specializations.through
    verbose_name = 'Specjalizacja'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Specjalizacja'

@admin.register(Specialization)
class SpecializationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name',]

@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SpecializationInline,]

    # this field is added as inline
    exclude = ['specializations',]
```

The resulting Django Admin Page looks like:
[image: django admin page view]

Everything is translated except of the 'Specialization' column. How can I change its name?

Comment: If you are here because you want to change the heading of a field which was added via `readonly_fields`, then you need to set "short_description" on the method which returns the readonly content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oke, this is not a full solution. But I hope this helps you out.
In the template that is called by `TabularInline` ,`admin/edit_inline/tabular.html`.

The part that builds your 'header' part of the table

```
 <thead><tr>
   ...
 {% for field in inline_admin_formset.fields %}
   {% if not field.widget.is_hidden %}
     <th{% if field.required %} class="required"{% endif %}>
        {{ field.label|capfirst }}
        ...
     </th>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 ...
 </tr></thead>
```

This is telling me you could add a label to a field. So by creating a custom form

```
class SpecializationForm(ModelForm):
    specializations = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Specialization.objects.all(), label='Specjalizacja')

    class Meta:
        model = Specialization
        fields = ('specializations', )
```

and call it in your `SpecializationInline`

```
class SpecializationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Doctor.specializations.through
    verbose_name = 'Specjalizacja'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Specjalizacja'
    form = SpecializationForm
```

This should allow you to change the text.

Comment: There should be queryset=Specialization.objects.all() for this to work, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Eagllus solution is good but the form can be simplified:

```
class SpecializationForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['specialization'].label = 'Specjalizacja'
```